# Maven dependencies available in one project but not another

Tags: java, maven-3

I have two projects that use identical pom files (one project is an earlier version of the second).  The second project compiles fine and allows me to use all the dependencies defined in the pom in my project.  However the first project does not, and it appears as though the dependencies are not even recognized by the project.

I looked in my local .m2 folder and see that the dependencies have been downloaded in their respective folders.  I even see the `mvn install` output says it has included the dependency, e.g.:

`Including com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6 in the shaded jar.`

And later...

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6 already exists in destination.`

I've tried `mvn clean` and the dependency is still not recognized. I've tried examining the contents of all of the pom files in the project and I can't see any difference between the two projects.

I'm convinced that there is something wrong with my project, but I'm not a maven expert.  Any ideas of where to look for the problem?

Here's an example of one of the dependencies that is not recognized:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here is my `mvn dependency:tree` ouput

```
[INFO] SwirldsProxy:SwirldsProxy:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- SwirldsPlatform:platform:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- SwirldsPlatform:fc:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- SwirldsPlatform:fcfs:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- SwirldsPlatform:fcutil:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- SwirldsPlatform:abcl-swirlds:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.abcl:abcl-contrib:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.12.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- SwirldsPlatform:fcfs-dep-fasl:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- SwirldsPlatform:fcdb:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- SwirldsPlatform:fcdb-dep-fasl:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.offbynull.portmapper:portmapper:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] \- com.github.davidmoten:flatbuffers-java:jar:1.6.0.2:compile
```

Apache Maven 3.5.0 Maven

Java version: 1.8.0_144-1-redhat

**UPDATE 8/30/2018**

So I discovered some interseting behavior.  My project location was under D:\SomeDirectory.  I tried moving it to C:\AnotherDirectory and performed `mvn install` and bingo, the dependencies were now available to my project.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the maven/java installation location, however I find it strange that I saw no errors when trying to run the maven commands, even when the project was under a different root directory (D:) compared to maven/java (C:).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include the output of mvn dependency:tree ?

Comment: @vaichidrewar Sure thing, added it to my question.

Comment: so some dependencies are getting included. Can you try to find out why those are included and may be that might give a clue about why others are not getting included?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the dependency is still not recognized." ?  What error message do you get, where?  The output line you quote is talking about Maven building these into a shaded jar file (which includes everything in a single jar) - are you then referencing that elsewhere?

Comment: @vaichidrewar I have tried looking through all my files and cannot find a reason why, hence the stack overflow question :)

Comment: @moilejter Forgive me, I'm pretty new to the Java world, my background is mostly in .NET.  When I say, "the dependency is still not recognized", I mean a couple things:  

1) I get "compile-time" errors for the import statements in my .java file, e.g `import com.java.code.gson`, saying that java can't find that namespace.  I can perform `mvn install` and `mvn build` but java intellisense still says it can't find the namespace.
2) I get a runtime error because the dependency is not resolved in the app

Comment: Hmm - if you can do a mvn build and mvn install without any compile-time errors, it sounds like Maven's build is finding everything it needs.  If your IDE does not find the code, it sounds like the IDE is not recognizing that what you have there is a Maven project, and so doesn't know to incorporate all those dependencies listed in the Maven pom.xml file.  I know that, in Eclipse, you have to tell it you have a Maven project, rather than a "regular" java project...

Comment: @moilejter I thought about that also... perhaps its an issue with the IDE.  I assumed that if the mvn build / clean worked, then it theory the project should have everything it needs.  But then when I run the .jar, it complains about the specific dependency in question.  I'm using Visual Studio Code with Redhat's Java extension, which I admit is not a first class citizen in the Java IDE world.  But it's strange that no other dependencies show the error.

Comment: Updated my question, found some new information.

Comment: Do you have the same errors when you use just maven from command line without the IDE?

Comment: @kedenk Yes, I always use `mvn install` from the command line.

Comment: @kedenk Can you try importing a project again? Follow instructions under "Importing a Maven project" section from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html . Importing a project using pom.xml should resolve dependencies.